# Change visibility in EventTrigger

Tags: wpf

i have style that have rectangle which visibility=hidden.

i want change visibility when mouse enter rectangle.

forasmuch as rectangle doesn't have 'IsMouseOver' property i cant use trigger.

how i can do that? (how can change property with animation)

thanks.

Comment: Actually as far as I can read from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.rectangle.aspx rectangle does have the Property IsMouseOver

Answer (score 0):

I've looking for an button to write a comment, but i dont found it.
So here comes an answer.

Two things:

How should it possible to set Visisbility of an Element to Visible, if it is hidden? The MouseEnter and MouseLeave events will not be called. So the IsMouseOver Property is always False.

Second thing is, that i'm wondering that the IsMouseOver Property will not work in a trigger (i've tried it, too and....got an exception).

An alternative way is to use EventTriggers on MouseEnter and MouseLeave.

kr
sb

Answer (score 0):

```
<Rectangle Width="400" Height="400" Fill="Red" Opacity="0">
        <Rectangle.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                <DoubleAnimation From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:2" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Rectangle.Style>
    </Rectangle>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to sum up and add to what others wrote:

The rectangle does have an IsMouseOver property. So it is possible to create a trigger (inside a style) that will work with this property. However, this will not work. Why? Because as far as WPF is concerned, if the element is not visible, the mouse is never over it. In other words, is the element is hidden, `IsMouseOver` will always be false. Therefore, you can't use it to make the element visible when the user puts the mouse over the place where it should be.

If you are working, with a Rectangle, there is another way: instead of making it not visible, you can change the Rectangle's color to be transparent. That way, it `IsMouseOver` will work as it should and the following code (as an example) will do what you want:

```
<Rectangle Width="200" Height="200">
    <Rectangle.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Yellow"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Rectangle.Style>
</Rectangle>
```

Of course, the usage depends on what exactly you want to do, which your question doesn't mention. Another way might be to create another Rectangle with the same dimensions and position as the one you need to hide/show. This new Rectangle would be transparent, but always visible. Then, you can bind your Rectangle's `Visibility` to this new Rectangle's `IsMouseOver`.

Answer (score -1):

Visibility has three enumeration, Visible Hidden and Collapsed, therefore you cant directly bind to a bool property or for that matter any property that is not a Visibility property. You can write or find a converter, search on WPF Visibility Converter. Or you can try this:

Use the tag property and bind it to the visibility property, it works fine, it is simple and it is entirely in your style setters and triggers. Of course if your using your tag for something else oh well..

In this case I have two TextBlocks, I want one textblock visible when the mouse enters the other, So when the mouse is over the first, I change its tag property to Visible and bind the second text box Visibility property to the firsts tag property.

```
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate  ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal ">
                        <TextBlock Name="TextBlockTitle" Text="{Binding Title}">
                            <TextBlock.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock }">
                                  <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Tag" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                                            <Setter Property="Tag" Value="Hidden"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBlock.Style></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Name="TextBlockAdd" Text=" + Add New" MouseLeftButtonDown="TextBlockAdd_OnMouseLeftButtonDown">
                            <TextBlock.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock }">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding ElementName=TextBlockTitle,Path=Tag}"></Setter>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeftButtonDown" ></EventTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBlock.Style>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>

                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```